# Android PayPalActivity not Fullscreen

Tags: java, android, paypal, popup, android-activity

I'm trying to include a PayPal donate button in my app (launching it from an actionbar button), it does work as it should, but...it just shows the PayPalActivity as a very small popup, while it should be almost fullscreen by default!

Let me explain better...
I use the usual piece of code to start the payment activity:

```
Intent checkoutIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(payment, this, new ResultDelegate());
startActivityForResult(checkoutIntent, 1);
```

Well, it starts the activity as expected, but it seems like "windowed" in a very small popup, while it should be a big popup almost fullscreen.
In the manifest i declare the usual needed parameters for PayPalActivity:

```
<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

and i also add the needed permissions...

What am i doing wrong?

I'm testing on a Galaxy S3 and using Android 4.0.3 APIs (but running 4.1.1 on phone)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Post your paypal activity's layout code

Comment: It has no layout code, the PayPalActivity is just an API from PayPal (in a jar file) and it should be called in the way i wrote above. The activity from where it is called is a PreferenceActivity that loads headers, so again no layout involved. Any help?

Comment: Have you tried `@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`?

Comment: You should probably know, that you are going to get into trouble using Paypal in your Android Apps. If you intend to distribute on the Google Play store. Google prefers that all methods of payment are done using the built in system. Please see point 3.3 of the developer agreement "All fees received by Developers for Products distributed via the Market must be processed by the Market's Payment Processor.". (I don't know if donations count in this case)

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a bug in the PayPal library.
Try setting

```
android:targetSdkVersion="3"
```

in your manifest file and you will get the full-screen popup.

Comment: Has anyone found a better solution?

Comment: This is an old problem but still not fixed: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/mobile/mobile-payment-libraries-mpl-issue-hi-density-and-recent-android-devices

Comment: refer to paypal's reply on github: basically you need to use PayPal Android SDK. https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/issues/11#issuecomment-27320092 https://github.com/paypal/sdk-packages/issues/21

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue for me:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
```

Hope it helps ;-)